# How can I check if a value already exists in a ListBox in Java Script

Tags: javascript, listbox, c#-3.0

The Answer for the code behind was given as follows:

```
if (!listBoxInstance.Items.Contains("some text")) // case sensitive is not important
            listBoxInstance.Items.Add("some text");
if (!listBoxInstance.Items.Contains("some text".ToLower())) // case sensitive is important  
            listBoxInstance.Items.Add("some text".ToLower());
```

Now how would this be done in Java Script?  TIA.

Comment: Assuming the `lisBoxInstance` is a C# listBox and you want to use JavaScript in lieu of C# on the server (not the client). Is this correct? If so, will you please update your question to clarify that?

Comment: Yes it is a C# Listbox.  I want to be able to check the value on the client side inside the aspx file using java script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this listBox.items an object?
If so:

```
if (!listBoxInstance.Items["some text"]) // case sensitive is not important
            listBoxInstance.Items["some text"] = // the value of the property you want to assign;
if (!listBoxInstance.Items[`${"some text".toLowerCase()}`]) // case sensitive is important  
            listBoxInstance.Items[`${"some text".toLowerCase()}`);
```